# MongoLab syntax error on import command

Tags: mongodb, import, syntax-error, mlab

I'm trying to import data into a MongoLab hosted mongo database.  I keep getting syntax errors.  I've used the tools->Pre-filled commands but it's not working.

[image]
Actually when I copy/paste from the Pre-filled example, the % doesn’t show in the command line tool.  Should it be a ‘%’ as it shows in the 'helper' or is it an error in html encoding?

I've got no experience with MongoLab nor with MongoDB for that matter.  Can anyone advise me about MongoLab as a hosting service for my Mongo db?

Thanks

Comment: You are correct, the `%` doesn't belong there. I'm not sure to which example you're referring, but the percent sign is likely a stand-in for whatever shell prompt you have configured. In your case, a `>`.

Comment: Actually you appear to be doing this **inside** the mongo shell. Do this from the **command line** instead.